# Do I need to use Spark with YARN to achieve NODE LOCAL data locality with HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

Do I need to use Spark with YARN to achieve NODE LOCAL data locality with HDFS?
If I use Spark standalone cluster manager and have my data distributed in HDFS cluster, how will Spark know that data is located locally on the nodes?

Answer (score 2):

YARN is a resource manager. It deals with memory and processes, and not with the workings of HDFS or data-locality.

Since Spark can read from HDFS sources, and the namenodes & datanodes take care of all that HDFS block data management outside of YARN, then I believe the answer is no, you don't need YARN. But you already have HDFS, which means you have Hadoop, so why not take advantage of integrating Spark into YARN?

Comment: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-data-locality.html

Comment: I mean, I could be wrong, but I know that a non YARN Spark can still read and write to HDFS. *"With HDFS the Spark driver contacts NameNode about the DataNodes (ideally local) containing the various blocks of a file or directory as well as their locations"* There may be additional parameters that running Spark on YARN allows

Answer (score 0):

the stand alone mode has its own cluster manager/resource manager which will talk to name node for locality. client/driver will put tasks based on the results.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).